# When is it okay to write "childrens" or "childrens' " – language hack

Tags: grammar, nouns, possessives, plural-forms, apostrophe

Let's make a scenario in which there are two distinctively different entities which are both referenced as "child".

The first entity is a group of nodes that are named "children" from the parent node (e.g. in Computer Science). The second entity is a group of kids who are human. For some arbitrary reason, someone tries to communicate both entities as a collective whole in a sentence but with a purpose to make the distinction.

Is it correct to use the word "childrens" to refer to both the children nodes and real-life children? Please note that I'm trying to use one word to symbolize different types of "children".

---

I asked the question just for fun during corona time.

Answer (score 2):

"Children" is already a plural noun so saying "childrens" would make no sense in English. In order to talk about all of the children while also indicating that they fall into different categories, you would have to refer to them as different types, sorts, varieties, kinds, etc. of children. For example, "Both kinds of children are ..."